# Assembly compilation error (gcc4.2.4=win, gcc4.3.3=fail)

Tags: c, assembly

We recently upgraded the code to `gcc4.3.3` from `gcc4.2.4`.

```
void testAndSet(  volatile int*  s, int* val )
{
   __asm__ __volatile__ ( "btsl   $0, %0\n   "
           "jc   bitSet\n   "
           "movl   $0, %1\n   "
           "jmp   returnVector\n"
           "bitSet:\n   "
           "movl   $1, %1\n"
           "returnVector: " : "=m"(*s), "=m"(*val) );
}
```

Our code now fails with the following errors,

```
lock.cxx: Assembler messages:
lock.cxx:59: Error: symbol `bitSet' is already defined
lock.cxx:61: Error: symbol `returnVector' is already defined
lock.cxx:59: Error: symbol `bitSet' is already defined
lock.cxx:61: Error: symbol `returnVector' is already defined
```

Those symbols weren't found anywhere else. (Renaming them causes the same error with the new name).

What's up with this? why do I get the errors twice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the optimizer has changed and is now inlining your testAndSet() function into 2 places.  Because you are using global names for your labels, this does not work.  You should use local names instead.  E.g:

```
   __asm__ __volatile__ ( "btsl   $0, %0\n   "
           "jc   0f\n   "
           "movl   $0, %1\n   "
           "jmp   1f\n"
           "0:\n   "
           "movl   $1, %1\n"
           "1: " : "=m"(*s), "=m"(*val) );
```

Local labels are just numbers; to disambiguate cases where there are many labels called "0" you need to use "`jmp 0f`" for forward jumps and "`jmp 0b`" for backward jumps.

Comment: Great. That was it. Interestingly, fails with the gcc option -02 but not with -O

Comment: The higher the value to the -O parameter, the more likely it is to inline things; essentially, -O2 and -O3 are going to use optimizations based around increasingly aggressive inlining and loop-unrolling, etc. It might be worth trying '-Os' (optimize without increasing code size) which often provides a good middle-ground optimization.

Answer (score 5):

This is unrelated to your error, but you could improve your code and avoid branches simply using the [setCC instruction](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/SETcc.htm):

```
   __asm__ __volatile__ ( "btsl   $0, %0\n   "
       "mov $0, %1\n"
       "setc %1\n" : "=m"(*s), "=m"(*val) );
```

The `setCC` instruction (where CC is one of the condition code flags, analogous to the `jCC` instruction) sets a byte to 0 or 1 depending on whether or not the given condition was satisfied.  Since the destination is a 4-byte value, you need to either preload it with 0 or use the [MOVZX instruction](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/MOVZX.htm) to make the upper 3 bytes 0.

Answer (score 2):

Also you may use local label names by adding **%=** after each local label:

"loop%=:"  "\n\t"