# Inline assembly with "jmp 0f" or "b 0f" at the beginning

Tags: assembly, pipeline, branch-prediction

**updated**

Changed the 2nd line of assembly to the mnemonic actually being used (`mflr`) and added more info at the bottom.

---

I ran across some code (using gcc) resembling the following (paraphrased):

```
#define SOME_MACRO( someVar ) \
do {                          \
  __asm__ (                   \
    "    b 0f\n"              \
    "0:  mflr %0\n"           \
    : "=r"( someVar )         \
  );                          \
} while(0)
```

... where the `b` instruction (ppc) is a short jmp and `mflr` is getting the contents of the 'link register' -- which is similar to the program counter in some respects.  I've seen this sort of thing for intel code as well (cf. the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878770/assembly-compilation-error-gcc4-2-4-win-gcc4-3-3-fail) question).

The branch acts as a no-op ... my question: what purpose does this serve?

I'm guessing it has something to do with branch prediction stuff, but so far I've only found people's code using this idiom while searching.

---

It looks like I was wrong on the branch prediction guess.  `mflr` grabs the contents of the link register.

So, my question boils down to: why is the branch necessary.

Comment: Could it be flushing the instruction prefetch queue?

Comment: Some of the purpose is in the `somethingelse`. Such code can be used for _instrumentation_ (debugging / runtime tracing). In x86, for example, `asm("call 0f\n0: pop %0\n" : "=r"(pc))` is a way to retrieve the program counter, `IP` (beware this isn't safe in 64bit mode). On ARM (and 64bit x86), the method is also often used to _embed constants_ within the code, for use with PC-relative loads. Whether there's an impact on branch prediction / pipelining depends on the CPU, so one cannot generally state "that's what it's for".

Comment: @FrankH. I spent some more time looking at the code; this is a great example of me not seeing the forest for the trees.  You're spot on with your analysis; `somethingelse` is getting the program counter and storing it in %0.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind posting your response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting bits of code like this tend to happen in `somethingelse`. Some known purposes of such code are:

- runtime state retrieval; In x86, for example,
  `__asm__("call 0f\n0: pop %0\n" : "=r"(pc))`
  is a way to retrieve the program counter (IP register - this is hidden and not directly accessible, so the fact `call` pushes it to the stack is used to retrieve it).
  Beware this isn't safe to use in leaf functions in 64bit mode due to the *red zone* - see [Inline assembly that clobbers the red zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380992/inline-assembly-that-clobbers-the-red-zone) .   The correct way to do it on x86_64 is
  `asm("lea 0f(%%rip), %0\n0:\n" : "=r"(pc))`
  which exploits the fact that PC-relative addressing is possible in 64bit mode.
- *instrumentation* (debugging / runtime tracing), e.g. by putting tracing code / `NOP` slots in there that tracing utilities at runtime can modify to dynamically hook into the code. Solaris DTrace uses such techniques.
- On ARM (and 64bit x86), the method is also used to *embed constants* within the code, for use with PC-relative loads.

Whether unconditional branches like this cause branch prediction miss penalties or other type of stalls is very CPU-dependent.

Comment: Would you like to speculate on why the branch would be necessary?

Comment: I dug through the ppc instruction set ... `b` doesn't alter the link register, but `bl` would.  So, there's three possible explanations I have right now: 1) there's some non-obvious side effect the branch produces, 2) they want the PC for code executed prior to `b 0f` -- which begs the question, why do `b 0f` at all ... and 3) the writers of this code expected `b 0f` to update LR, so the code isn't doing what they expect.